# Azure TCPListener worker role receiving unknown connections

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, tcplistener, azure-monitoring

I have written an Azure Worker Role which sets up a TCPListener and receives messages. These messages are then routed to different service bus queues dependent on their content. The Worker Role code is below:

```
private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TcpListener listener;
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;

    ipEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["MainEndpoint"].IPEndpoint;
    listener = new TcpListener(ipEndPoint) { ExclusiveAddressUse = false };
    listener.Start();

    _log.Info($"Created and started listener on {ipEndPoint.Address}:{ipEndPoint.Port}");

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AsyncMessageHandler, listener);
        _connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}

private void AsyncMessageHandler(IAsyncResult result)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    try
    {
        _log.Debug("Session initiated");

        var listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
        var client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);

        _connectionWaitHandle.Set();

        var netStream = client.GetStream();
        bytes = new byte[short.MaxValue];
        netStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Warn("An error occurred receiving a message", ex);
    }

    // Do stuff with message
}
```

On my development machine everything is working as expected; messages are being received when I send them using a console application and no other messages are being received.

In Azure (Classic Cloud Service) however, from the logs I can see that we are receiving connections that are not instigated by us. These connections result in a "connection forcibly closed by remote host" exception when we try to read from the stream:

```
netStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

- Could it be something in the Azure architecture that is monitoring the service to ensure it is listening on the port configured in the Endpoint config?
- Is there any way of identifying these connections? At present, I've wrapped the code in a try/catch but I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I think I might be experiencing the same thing

Comment: Sorry this is a bit late; might help someone though. We worked out that it was the Azure architecture monitoring the service. We just had to change our code to ignore this scenario.

Comment: ahhh that sounds like a potential option.  When you mean change your code do you mean there was a special option you set or did you add to the exception block you mentioned above?